# "You should never modify something you are iterating over". How do I modify it then?

Tags: python, pandas

I've read in [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) and many comments here that you should never modify something you are iterating over.

Let's say I have this `dataframe`:

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame({'name':['jim','john','mary','michael'],
                    'age':[12,46,44,32]})

      name  age
0      jim   12
1     john   46
2     mary   44
3  michael   32
```

And I want to do the following things:

**1.** If the name begins with `j`, add `'smith'` to the name.

**2.** If the age is greater than 40, multiply it by 2.

So I create a function to do this:

```
def modify(df):

    for i in range(len(df)):

        # if age is >40
        if df.loc[i,'age'] > 40:

            # multiply it by 2
            df.loc[i,'age'] = df.loc[i,'age']*2

        # get the name
        name = df.loc[i,'name']

        # if it starts with 'j'
        if name[0]=='j':

            # add 'smith' to the name
            name = name+' '+'smith'

        # insert into cell    
        df.loc[i,'name'] = name
```

Apply the function:

```
modify(mydf)
```

Result:

```
print(mydf)

         name  age
0   jim smith   12
1  john smith   92
2        mary   88
3     michael   32
```

This worked fine. So what's the problem?

Should I instead make a copy of the dataframe and return it at the end? Like the following:

```
def modify(df):

    df = df.copy()

    for i in range(len(df)):

        if df.loc[i,'age'] > 40:

            df.loc[i,'age'] = df.loc[i,'age']*2

        name = df.loc[i,'name']

        if name[0]=='j':

            name = name+' '+'smith'

        df.loc[i,'name'] = name

    return df
```

However, **I am still editing something I am iterating over**. So I guess this is still bad?

**Note:** I am working on a function that is much larger and more complex than this, with more conditions and api calls etc. that goes through 100,000 rows of customer data. e.g. if customer is from city X, `do this`, if customer is from city Y, `do that` etc etc. So I am not looking for a solution to this exact dataframe.

I just want to know what to do if you have to iterate and edit over rows when it is totally not recommended.

Comment: If you are iteration over a dataframe in pandas, there is generally always a better way I'll throw up an answer in a sec.

Comment: Keep in mind *what* you are modifying. If you are iterating over a list, it is fine to change the *contents* of an element of the list. It is not (or may not be) fine to add or remove elements from the list altogether. The difference is that the former does not change the *structure* of the list, while the latter does.

Comment: I am happy to see that you've taken note of a very important phrase, and are asking a question over it. However, note that the comment refers not to a "translation/mapping" of contents but rather a change in the size of the container itself!

Comment: I don't know anything about Pandas specifically.  Speaking generally, though, the solution often is not to modify the sequence at all, but to create a _new_ sequence that contains only the items you want.  Another common solution is to go ahead and modify the sequence, but start iterating from the _end_, so that when you remove an item, the indexes at the front of the list remain undisturbed.

Answer (score 0):

You should always escape from `for` loop while using `pandas`. `pandas` stands for optimizing those loops.

Here is the code that solves your problem:

```
idx_smith = mydf[mydf["name"].str.startswith("j")].index
idx_age = mydf[mydf["age"] > 40].index
mydf.loc[idx_smith, "name"] = mydf.loc[idx_smith].name + " smith"
mydf.loc[idx_age, "age"] = mydf.loc[idx_age].age*2

mydf

    name    age
0   jim smith   12
1   john smith  92
2   mary    88
3   michael 32
```

An answer to your question:
You should use for iterating for row operations **pandas apply with lambda** for efficient memory/cpu usage.

Comment: In my opinion, `mydf.loc[idx_smith, 'name']` is way more readable than `mydf.loc[idx_smith].name`, which by the way, means another thing. Also, i suspect `mydf.loc[idx_smith,'name'] += 'smith'` would also work.

Comment: `.loc['a', 'b']` and `.loc['a'].b` are different things